# Lines connecting elements in an equation

Tags: pstricks, tikzmark

I want to draw lines connecting various elements in an equation.
Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand\connect[1]{
\draw[->] ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]pic cs:start#1) 
    to ([shift={(2pt,8pt)}]pic cs:end#1);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\{a, \tikzmark{startB1}b, c, \tikzmark{startD1}d\} \\ \\
\{\tikzmark{endB1}b, \tikzmark{endD1}d\}
\end{gather*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,line width=0.5pt]
\connect{B1}
\connect{D1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{gather*}
\{a, \tikzmark{startB2}bbbb, c, \tikzmark{startD2}dddd\} \\ \\
\{\tikzmark{endB2}bbbb, \tikzmark{endD2}dddd\}
\end{gather*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,line width=0.5pt]
\connect{B2}
\connect{D2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hard coded various numbers (such as 2pt, 8pt, etc) after finding them by trial and error.

Is there a way to automate this without entering hard coded numbers? I want the line to be centered at the bottom of the top element and at the top of the bottom element. For example, `bbbb` is considered one element.

I also wonder, if there is an entirely different way to do this that is simpler.

**Clarification:**
In the above image, the second set of equations is not correctly rendered. Both ends of the arrows should have been centered on `bbbb` and `dddd`.

Comment: What I usually do is create two marks e.g. one on the left of bbbb and one on the right and then use the `calc` library to get the point halfway between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a bit with tikz, and this is the result (I only show the second example, since that seem to be the problematic one):

[image: First variant]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\{a,
\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[anchor=base,inner xsep=0pt] (b1) {$bbbb$};},
c,
\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[anchor=base,inner xsep=0pt] (d1) {$dddd$};}\} \\ \\
\{\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[anchor=base,inner xsep=0pt] (b2) {$bbbb$};},
\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[anchor=base,inner xsep=0pt] (d2) {$dddd$};}\}
\end{gather*}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[->] (b1.south) to (b2.north);}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[->] (d1.south) to (d2.north);}
\end{document}
```

An alternative is to change the last two lines into something like

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[->,shorten <=1.2ex,shorten >=1.2ex] (b1.center) to (b2.center);}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[->,shorten <=1.2ex,shorten >=1.2ex] (d1.center) to (d2.center);}
```

The result then looks like below:

[image: Alternative variant]

I guess it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 5):

It is very simple to do with `pstricks`, and more specifically with `pst-node` and `auto-pst-pdf`: put everything in a `postscript` environment, define the elements you want to join as nodes, and connect these nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
  \psset{nodesep=2pt, linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15}
  \begin{gather*}
    \{a, \rnode{B1}b, c, \rnode{D1}d\} \\[3ex]
    \{\rnode{B2}b, \rnode{D2}d\}
    \ncline{B1}{B2}\ncline{D1}{D2}
  \end{gather*}
  %
  \begin{gather*}
    \{a, \rnode{B1}{bbbb}, c, \rnode{D1}{dddd} \} \\ \\
    \{\rnode{B2}{bbbb}, \rnode{D2}{dddd}\}
    \ncline{B1}{B2}\ncline{D1}{D2}
  \end{gather*}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean they have to  in the first line? Or should the arrows join the groups of bbbb and dddd?

Comment: I see. I'll edit in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a start:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (magic0) at (0,1) [matrix of nodes]{
    \{ & aaaaaaa, & bbbb, & c, & dd & \}\\
  };

  \matrix (magic1) at (0,0) [matrix of nodes]{
    \{ & a, & b, & cc, & ddd & \} \\
  };

  \draw[thick,->] (magic0-1-3) -- (magic1-1-4);
  \draw[thick,->] (magic0-1-2) -- (magic1-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[tikz/pgf manual p.646](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)

[image: output]